# Why the character does not immediately move from animation "run" to animation "idle" and Vice versa?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to gamedev and started with Unity. I can't find information on how to make a character walk and run using animation.

I tried to do as it is written on this site, but my code did not work https://habr.com/ru/post/211847/. in unity itself, in "animator" section in "idle" conditions - speed-greater-0.01, and in "run" conditions - speed-less-0.01.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCntrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;

    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    private Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(speed * moveX, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(moveX));

        if (moveX > 0)
        {
            FlipRight();
        }
        else if (moveX < 0)
        {
            FlipLeft();
        }

        void FlipLeft()
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1, 1);
        }
        void FlipRight()
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the animator you can change the speed of animations and transitions. Click an animation state to change its speed and click a transition to change it's exit time and duration. Play around with it until you find the settings that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Animator. Click on the Transition between your two states and uncheck the *Has Exit Time* property.

[image]